# Paypal Shopping Carts and Buy Now Button with Bookmarklets

Tags: jquery, paypal, e-commerce, checkout

I have tried to research this but cannot find the exact detail to know whether this is technically possible or not. I have a "javascript/jquery" bookmarklet that I created using JQUERY "http://blog.reybango.com/2010/09/02/how-to-easily-inject-jquery-into-any-web-page/" It lets me inject jquery and I can inject HTML into the page.

Using the same technology I can also inject the static "Paypal Buy now Button" with a link to "Pay Now". Is there a way I could mantain a "Paypal Shopping Cart" ? If the customer keeps shopping and wants to checkout later.

I would appreciate if you have any other solutions or technical possibilities as well. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [add to cart](http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/) buttons.  This would allow the buyer to keep adding items to the cart.  You could also create a view cart button as well.